# Use pdoc3 to get user formatted output

Tags: python

I have to analyze a whole bunch of previously created `.py` files from a folder and gather info from them to store it in a DB. That info shall include the name of all the functions in every `.py` file along with their parameters, and the optional documentation obtained from Docstring (if available) for any function.

Using `pdoc3` I start with this source:

```
import math

def Add(val1, val2):
    """
    Adds two values.
    
    Author: Mike Smith.
    
    Args:
        val1 (int): First value.
        val3 (int): Second value.
    
    Returns:
        int: va1 plus val2.
    """
    return val1 + val2

def Sqrt(val):
    return math.sqrt(val)
```

And I am getting this text output:

```
Module functions
================

Functions
---------

    
`Sqrt(val)`
:   

    
`Add(val1, val2)`
:   Adds two values.
    
    Author: Mike Smith.
    
    Args:
        val1 (int): First value.
        val3 (int): Second value.
    
    Returns:
        int: va1 plus val2.
```

As you can see, some problems have arosen: If the comment states val3 instead of val2, no warning or error is emited. Also, non keywords (as author) are just given as plain text in html. Last, the output format is very verbose for being parsed for a second program.

I wonder, is there any way to change the output format for a chosen one, including the desired keywords+structure and with some warning if Docstrings does not match with arguments or returns?

NOTE: I am willing to change Docstring style (currently using Google's) or document generator tool if my request can not achieved with these ones listed above.

Thanks!

Comment: I think pdoc3 doesn't analyze the docstring, it just take them as-is. Maybe sphinx/napoleon may be a better option to parse Google-style docstring (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html)

Comment: But not sure it performs validation against function signature.

Comment: Numpydoc provide a validation mechanism with numpy docstring (https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validation.html)

Comment: @zigarn Thank you very much! I will check out both sphynx and numpydoc. Maybe I begin with Numpydoc, because lots of people say that Sphynx is a little bit overkill